# #!/usr/bin/env python: Getting command not found and Permission Denied

Tags: python, pygtk

I have at the top of the file `#!/usr/bin/env python`. So it should work when I run the file? But it doesnt. It works when I use `python file.py` tho

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk 

class App1:
  def __init__(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.show()

  def main(self):
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = App1()
  app.main()
```

Python Here is what happened:

```
jiewmeng@jiewmeng:/labs/projects/learnPython$ app1.py
app1.py: command not found
jiewmeng@jiewmeng:/labs/projects/learnPython$ ./app1.py
bash: ./app1.py: Permission denied
jiewmeng@jiewmeng:/labs/projects/learnPython$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 jiewmeng jiewmeng 4096 2011-07-16 22:08 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 jiewmeng jiewmeng 4096 2011-07-16 21:45 ../
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jiewmeng jiewmeng  256 2011-07-16 22:05 app1.py*
```

Comment: Does the python interpreter launch if you simply do `/usr/bin/env python` from the command line?

Comment: You get `command not found` because `.` is not in `$PATH` (execute `PATH=$PATH:. app1.py` and that particular error won't happen).

Comment: @jiewmeng - Did you solved this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chris makes an excellent suggestion in the comments to the question, and Peter's answer covers what you should do if Chris' suggestion doesn't work and you are in the *sudoer* group on your system (i.e. if you can modify files other than those belonging to your user). What follows could be your next option.

In a command shell, type:

```
which python
```

this command will tell you where your working installation of python is located. Then you can modify the shebang line in your python file accordingly. For example, on my system:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

thus my shebang would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Be aware that this will make your file work on your system but it's highly probable it will make it not runnable on other ones...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the most likely problem is /usr/bin/env is not executable by you.  Try `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/env`. Definitely this is not the normal state so someone must have manually borked up the permissions on /usr/bin/env.

Comment: I don't believe that this is it. With bash 4.2.8 on Ubuntu 11.04, if I give it bad permissions I get `bash: ./file.py: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission denied`.

Answer (score 0):

What happened with a basic python code like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print "Hello World !"
```

Maybe the problem is with GTK or other but not with `#!/usr/bin/env python` ?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10: Start button -> "manage app execution aliases" -> turn all off

Error reason: when you type "python" in cmd, it opens microsoft store.